# How to represent combination data in JSON?

Tags: node.js, json, spring, api-design

I am implementing an API that returns how many users are using a particular app.

For example, say I want to return data that says

10 people are using only App1, 8 are using only App2, 8 are using only App3, and 15 are using both App1 and App2, and 20 are using all App1, App2, and App3.

How do we design the response structure in JSON?

I thought returning it in comma separated format

```
{
  "App1": 10,
  "App2": 8,
  "App3": 8,
  "App1,App2": 15,
  "App1,App2,App3": 20
}
```

Is this format is right and semantically correct?

I thought of Array as well,

```
[
   {"key": ["App1"], "count": 10},
   {"key": ["App2"], "count": 8},
   {"key": ["App3"], "count": 8},
   {"key": ["App1", "App2"], "count": 15},
   {"key": ["App1", "App2", "App3"], "count": 20}
]
```

but was doubtful on this on whether it is semantically correct.

Is there any better way? What is the best way to represent this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of this problem as three overlapping population in a Venn diagram. The best way to represent a Venn diagram is to represent each section as an *ordered list* of constituents and the number associated with it. This will uniquely represent each section to make a whole.

[image: The Venn Diagram]

Now this goal is achieved by both the solutions. But the CSV as the keys of the JSON has a couple of flaws:

1. The Typescript definition will be difficult. In the first case, your Typescript definition would be a `Record<string, number>` which is not as strongly typed (read less specificity) as the second one, which is

   ```js
   type App = 'App1' | 'App2' | 'App3';
   type AppUsage = Array<{ key: Array<App>, count: number }>;
   ```
2. The first type is brittle. What if an app name has a comma? Your clients have to know the format. How would they differentiate between, say, `"App1,App2"` vs `"App1, App2"` (notice the space after the comma?). It is generally suggested to not use format dependent identifiers. Arrays are easier to work with and provide a better consistency.
3. If you use GraphQL, using plain `JSON`, which is what the first approach is, is generally considered a bad practice.

So, the bottomline this should be the better way,

```js
type App = 'App1' | 'App2' | 'App3';
type AppUsage = Array<{ key: Array<App>, count: number }>;

const appUsage: AppUsage = [
   {"key": ["App1"], "count": 10},
   {"key": ["App2"], "count": 8},
   {"key": ["App3"], "count": 8},
   {"key": ["App1", "App2"], "count": 15},
   {"key": ["App1", "App2", "App3"], "count": 20}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the following structure:

```json
{
  "usersCount": [
    {
      "apps": ["App1"],
      "userCount": 10
    },
    {
      "apps": ["App2"],
      "userCount": 8
    },
    {
      "apps": ["App3"],
      "userCount": 8
    },
    {
      "apps": ["App1", "App2"],
      "userCount": 15
    },
    {
      "apps": ["App1", "App2", "App3"],
      "userCount": 20
    }
  ]
}
```

This would make it easier to parse and handle multiple Apps (when compared with String split for example). To make it a little bit more strongly typed I would make `App1`, `App2` and `App3` values of an `App` enumeration.

Comment: @Aniket, do you have any questions about my answer? Is it not clear or missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution you have tried is very limited. Your solution is fine for 3 apps but let's say that you later want to add few more apps then you have add those return types as well.

Instead of the above I would like to suggest as below. This suggestion has low coupling and can work for any number of apps

```
{
  "IndividualAppUsersCount":[10,8,8],
  "MultipleAppUsersCount":[ 
    {
      "AppsInUse":"App1+App2",
      "Count":15
    },
    {
      "AppsInUse":"App1+App2+App3",
      "Count":20
    }
  ]
}
```

The benefit of using this approach is that you are not limited to predefined apps but can easily work for 0 to n number of apps. Just loop through the array and get the corresponding result.

You can even improve the above result by following as below.

```
{

  "AppUsersCount":[
    {
      "AppsInUse":"App1",
      "Count":10
    },
    {
      "AppsInUse":"App2",
      "Count":8
    },
    {
      "AppsInUse":"App3",
      "Count":8
    },
    {
      "AppsInUse":"App1, App2",
      "Count":15
    },
    {
      "AppsInUse":"App1, App2, App3",
      "Count":20
    }
  ]
}
```

I hope this answers your question. However if you still have any other question, let me know I will be glad to answer.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: @ramiz fail to understand as why you're saying my answer as limited. I have given an example using 3 Apps just like the way you've given in your answer. There is no problem in adding another key with comma separated when there are more apps tomorrow. There is no coupling in any way.

Comment: Hi @Aniket, I am glad you asked. Your code is correct but I would not recommend that as it will be difficult to manage as your code grows.
What I meant by limited is that when you will try to parse the JSON, you have to specifically read those keys(i.e. "App1", "App2", etc..). Hence if you add a new key(i.e. "App_n"), then you have to add that logic in the code as well. 
Hope you understand the pain point now, else let me know.